# If we need to create a URL for stream, why can we set video.src to stream for WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

In a Google's [WebRTC tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#3), it has the following example code.

I have two questions for it:

1. Why do we need to set *window.stream* to *stream*? (What does
   "*stream available to console*" mean?)
2. If we need to create a URL for *stream*, why can we set *video.src*
   to stream which should be a blob?

Thanks.

```
function successCallback(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
  if (window.URL) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  } else {
    video.src = stream;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's setting a globally accessible variable called stream - you could call it `fred` - it doesn't matter - it's just for global access

Comment: Thanks!! How about the second question? Can you enlighten me for this one please?

Comment: If I had answers I'd post answers - hence why I only posted a comment, as I only knew the simple half of your two questions :p

Comment: The second question is for cross-browser support: Chrome uses the `createObjectURL()` function and Firefox can use just the steam by itself. [Source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/02/cross-browser-camera-capture-with-getusermediawebrtc/): "Chrome uses the createObjectURL method whereas Firefox and Opera send the stream directly"

Comment: @SamuelMéndez Unfortunately, the code is wrong. Luckily the `else` clause never executes in practice. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Old and wrong code. `video.src = stream` is wrong. It should be `video.srcObject = stream`. It just never runs because all browsers today support [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/URL).

Instead, use [`srcObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject) whenever available (supported in both Chrome and Firefox) for better life time handling by browsers:

```
if (typeof video.srcObject == "object") {
  video.srcObject = stream;
} else {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
```

Or use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) and don't worry about it:

```
video.srcObject = stream;
```

Oh, and `window.stream` is just some global variable. Likely used for debugging by the sample author.

2013 is old for WebRTC code. I recommend looking at the official [WebRTC samples](https://github.com/webrtc/samples#webrtc-code-samples) instead.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thanks ;)