# How can I use Axios to display images or videos using html img/video tag?

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, axios

I am working on a react app (typescript template) with axios and asp.net core 3.1 for backend api. And, for instance, I have this protected (Identity with JWT) endpoint to get an image file from server as `FileStream`:

```
[Authorize(Policy = AspianCorePolicy.AdminAttachmentGetImagePolicy)]
[HttpGet("images/{filename}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetImage(string filename)
{
     var imageDto = await Mediator.Send(new GetImage.Query { FileName = filename });
     return File(imageDto.Memory, imageDto.MimeType, imageDto.FileName);
}
```

And take it into consideration that, I have some **large video files** to stream too.

- With that being said, if I want **to use Axios to get it as file stream and display it in** an `img` or a `video` tag **or even download the file**, how can I do that through Axios and html tag? Should I use Axios `responseType: 'stream'` ? And if so, how can I exactly do that?

Comment: Have you thought of converting the image to a base64 string in the server side code and using that in the img tag instead of a static file? e.g. <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, [BASE64 STRING HERE...]" />

Comment: Actually yes. But whatever you do in the server side then you have to receive the result as an Axios Promise<Blob> or something, So, you will have a problem with authentication and everything plus receiving a Promise<Blob> as a result has its own complexities. I've been recently thinking of using direct url to the endpoint then checking my refresh token of httponly cookie in the server side to see if the user is kind of authenticated.

Comment: Why not just assign your api url to img/video tags directly?

Comment: @Evk As I said in the question, because the endpoint is protected and I want it to be protected so to get a result I have to be authenticated and therefore I must send JWT among request headers every time I send an http request to get an image as an example, and, I can't do that with img tag or "a" tag because they don't accept headers to send.

Comment: You can pass token in a cookie (cookie is also a header after all), or you can fetch it via ajax and then use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL on response.That url can then be assigned to img.src

Comment: @Evk I am using Axios so it is responsible for xhr and everything because as I mentioned I am using React. and it is not the best practice to send token in cookies because if it is httponly restricted then you will be vulnerable to CSRF attacks and if it is not then JWT will be accessible through javascript. I only keep JWT in memory and use "refresh token" in an httponly cookie and yeah based on that I will be able to recognize the user, but it will need database connection and not efficient that much so if I could use JWT that would be awesome and I can only do that through Axios requests.

Comment: So I guess set response type to 'blob' and then use createObjectURL(response.data)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091530/if-we-need-to-create-a-url-for-stream-why-can-we-set-video-src-to-stream-for-we

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The axios api is straight forward. You can find [axios browser examples](http://zetcode.com/javascript/axios/) here.

To show an image or a video would be quite similar.

Setup the call to retrieve a blob response from the web api.

```
var config = { responseType: 'blob' }
```

Then make the call and create a data url from the blob. The data url can then be set on a target element:

Image

```
axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestImage.png", config)
    .then(resp => {
        $("#img1").attr("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(resp.data));
    });
```

Video

```
axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestVideo.mp4", config)
    .then(resp => {
        $("#video1").attr("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(resp.data));
    });
```

Downloading would file a similar process, except you set the href on an html anchor element with the download attribute set to true. This can be done programmatically to click the link after creating it (inspired by this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Tomassito/a5b4d29f459b9383dc3daa313ae5f73b))

Image

```
axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestImage.png", config)
    .then(resp => {
        download(resp);
    });
```

Video

```
axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestVideo.mp4", config)
    .then(resp => {
        download(resp);
    });
```

And the download function

```
function download(resp) {
    var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(resp.data);
    var fileName = resp.headers["content-disposition"].split("filename=")[1].split(";")[0];
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    $(link).attr("href", url).attr("download", fileName);
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

As far as the `responseType: 'stream'` I was unable to get it to work in the browser. Per Axios Github, [streaming is currently not supported in browsers](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/479) due to the use of XHR requests.

Putting it all together, with a working web api endpoint at the route you specified, this would be working code sample.

```js
$(document).ready(() => bindHandlers());
var urlCreator;

function bindHandlers() {
  urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  $("#btnShowImage").click(() => btnShowImageClick());
  $("#btnShowVideo").click(() => btnShowVideoClick());
  $("#btnDownloadImage").click(() => btnDownloadImageClick());
  $("#btnDownloadVideo").click(() => btnDownloadVideoClick());
  $("img1").hide();
  $('#videoWrapper').hide();
}
var config = {
  responseType: 'blob'
}

function btnShowImageClick() {
  axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestImage.png", config)
    .then(resp => {
      $("#img1").attr("src", urlCreator.createObjectURL(resp.data));
      $("#img1").show();
      $('#videoWrapper').hide();
    });
}

function btnShowVideoClick() {
  axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestVideo.mp4", config)
    .then(resp => {
      $("#img1").hide();
      $("#video1").attr("src", urlCreator.createObjectURL(resp.data))
      $('#videoWrapper').show();
    });
}

function btnDownloadImageClick() {
  axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestImage.png", config)
    .then(resp => {
      download(resp);
    });
}

function btnDownloadVideoClick() {
  axios.get("api/media?fileName=TestVideo.wmv", config)
    .then(resp => {
      download(resp);
    });
}

function download(resp) {
  var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(resp.data);
  var fileName = resp.headers["content-disposition"]
    .split("filename=")[1].split(";")[0];
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  $(link).attr("href", url).attr("download", fileName);
  link.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.21.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4">Axios Example</h1>
  <input id="btnShowImage" value="Show Image" type="button" />
  <input id="btnShowVideo" value="Show Video" type="button" />
  <input id="btnDownloadImage" value="Download Image" type="button" />
  <input id="btnDownloadVideo" value="Download Video" type="button" />
  <img id="img1" />
  <div id="videoWrapper">
    <video id="video1" controls="controls"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough solution and for your time Alexander. Actually my problem was that I was unable to get responseType: 'stream' to work in the browser too so I thought I did something wrong then I asked about it here. So, if I use blob even for large video files there won't be a problem? Another question is, do I have to wait every time I ask for a video file till the file is completely received and after that I can play the video or it will be receiving in ranges like video streaming and I can play it in the meanwhile?

Comment: I checked Udemy's tutorials' preview video links and they are blobs too and every tutorial's links displayed into a Modal. So if we suppose that I have a Modal with 10 "a" tag containing "href=blob..." then wouldn't the page or Modal load slowly because of waiting for Axios response to receive for every and each one of them?

Comment: Technically, BlobURL is going to reference to a Blob or a File that has already been loaded into memory in the browser so there will be no lag using them. For practical purposes though, yet the data needs to be completed downloaded before they are created. Odds are you  wouldn't load 10 large videos into blobs in the first place. You would display a thumbnail for them and have the video on a page by itself. You will run into browser and server side memory constraints loading very large blobs into memory.